# Transistor used in 3 GHz LNA

Tags: rf, identification, reverse-engineering

I've got this 3GHz RF amplifier off [ebay](https://www.ebay.de/itm/164270336676), and I'm trying to figure out how it works. I've took the RF shield off, but the markings on the component that I assume is the transistor, are scratched off.

What transistor could have been used here?

Also, how can this thing work with just one transistor?

Here is a photo of my device:

[image]

The underside of the PCB is just a ground pour

Comment: What makes you think it is a single transistor? More likely at least two (or more) plus biasing resistors.

Comment: @glen_geek I've seen photos of similar devices, which had two of these components. And since I found lots of schematics for RF amplifiers with two transistors, I assumed these were the transistors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schematic of the circuit is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffzsvI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 appears to be an integrated RF amplifier, not a transistor. I imagine that any transistor in an amplifier like this would require a DC path on all 3 of its terminals, whereas pin P1 is open at DC, so a transistor would work very poorly and wouldn't really amplify much.